# Detect Android App keyboard's language selected in custom app regardless locale

Tags: android

Regardless of locale I want to write Android app code which applies fonts based on this app keyboard selected (soft input selected).

```
if (keyboard language is persian) {
apply font family persianFont and do not apply this font on existing characters
}

else if (language is English) {
apply Signika font and do not apply this font on existing characters
}

else (for every other language)  use default fonts operating system allows
```

If you answer the question please note:
I need code to detect keyboard language and apply font family and font sizes in that language without affecting existing text.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do this.  Keyboards are separate apps, and they handle language display on their own.  There is no API for the OS to query what language they're displaying, or for the keyboard to tell the OS what language its using.  The best you can do is get the OS locale, which is they language the user requested for strings to be displayed in.  But you cannot detect if their keyboard is set to a language other than the locale.